# how to optimize sql query with indexes

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this complicated query and I need to optimize that.
Without indexes it takes 20ms, I'tried add some indexes, its better, now I have 4ms.
But I dont have any experience. Can you help me to make it even faster?

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM(
   SELECT user_id FROM times 
      INNER JOIN tags ON times.user_id = tags.tag_id 
      INNER JOIN users ON tags.user_nr = users.nr  
      WHERE (times.time < 1597313) 
        AND (times.run_id="118") 
        AND (times.user_id != 109330258) 
        AND (times.user_id != 0) 
        AND (times.time != 0 ) 
        AND (times.cell != 1 ) 
        AND (users.category_id="4") 
        GROUP BY user_id HAVING count(*) == 1 
   UNION  
   SELECT user_id FROM times 
   INNER JOIN tags ON times.user_id = tags.tag_id 
   INNER JOIN users ON tags.user_nr = users.nr  
   WHERE (times.run_id="118") 
     AND (times.user_id != 109330258) 
     AND (times.user_id != 0 ) 
     AND (times.time != 0 ) AND (times.cell != 1 ) 
     AND (users.category_id="4") 
     GROUP BY user_id HAVING count(*) > 1
   )
```

I added 3 indexes.

- table tags - tagid
- table times - user_id
- table user - nr

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQLite? You tagged as both

Comment: "its better, now I need 4ms". How much is it now? How much data do you have in these tables? How did you determine what indexes to add? What does the query plan (explain) look like?

Comment: its sqlite(tag removed), now I HAVE 4 ms(edited)

Answer (score 0):

You should also try indexing tags.user_nr, but it's impossible to give a definitive answer without seeing the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about MySQL [here in Stack Exchange on the database administrator site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16172/trying-to-optimize-query-for-performance-mysql) you have a similar question, not exactly the same, but the OP is trying to optimize performance on a big query like yours. Pay attention to the 2nd answer, it gives helpfull tips on hot to tune your queries.